# JQGrid - td title change on ok of popup box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have editable row in `jqgrid`. On double click of `textbox`, it will open a popup box having `textarea`.

On clicking `OK` of popup, i need `textarea` value back to `jqgrid` row cell, from where double click is called.

Value of cell is inside `title` attribute of `td`.

I tried to change title attribute using `rowid`, but `jqgrid` cell does not reflects with my new value.

```
tr='#'+top_id;
$(tr).find('td[aria-describedby="Remarks"]').attr('title','txtremark.value');
```

It also shows value changed in developer tools, inspect element. But cell value is not changed.

I tried to reload grid on ok `click` event and, `onloadcomplete` event of grid again set `title` attribute. But problem remains same.
Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    I got an answer of this.. On jqgrid's ondblClickRow event I set a title attribute to popup textbox as below.

    txtremark.value = $(tr).find('td[aria-describedy="Remarks"]').attr('title');

    Then, on Ok button click event i reload jqgrid,
    and after that on LoadComplete event again I set attribute of title and also set html of title like,





loadcomplete : function(){
        tr ="#" + rowid;
        $(tr).find('td[aria-describedy="Remarks"]').attr('title',txtremark.value);
        $(tr).find('td[aria-describedy="Remarks"]').html(txtremark.value);
        $("divremarks").dialog('close');
        });


    Its compulsory to set html of td other wise next time you got undefined in popup window.
```